# sequelize js count result set model association

Tags: node.js, instance, sequelize.js, getter-setter, class-method

I've three models

1. post
2. postTag
3. tag

I just like to add tag count while getting postTag.
Here is my getPost function

```js
models.post.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.postTag,
      //include:[{model:models.tag}],
      //attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn('count', models.sequelize.col('postTags.post_id')), 'count']]
    }
  ],
    where: postData.where
})
```

here is my PostTag model

```js
var models = require('../models');
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('postTag',
    {
      post_id: {
          type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true
      },
      tag_id: {
          type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true
      },
      order_no: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      create_time: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName : 't_post_tag',
      classMethods:
        {
          associate: function (models) {
          models.postTag.belongsTo(models.post,{  foreignKey :"post_id", targetKey:"post_id" });
          //models.postTag.belongsTo(models.tag,{  foreignKey :"tag_id", targetKey:"tag_id" });
        }
        },
        instanceMethods: {
          tag_name: function () {
              return models.tag.findById(this.getDataValue('tag_id'));
          },
          count: function(){
            // please  complete this
          }
        },
        getterMethods: {
            // tag_name: function () {
            //     return models.tag.findById(this.getDataValue('tag_id'));
            // }
        },
        setterMethods: {

        }
    }
    );
  }
</code></pre>

Now i'm gtting this response
<pre><code>
{
  "status": true,
  "response": [
    {
      "create_time": "Tue Nov 22 2016",
      "post_id": "38",
      "description": "good palce",
      "create_by": 67,
      "update_time": "2016-11-22T15:32:22.985Z",
      "country_id": 156,
      "postTags": [
        {
          "post_id": 38,
          "tag_id": 8,
          "order_no": 1,
          "create_time": "2016-11-21T18:30:00.000Z",
          "tag": {
            "tag_id": 8,
            "tag_name": "Hiking",
            "tag_type": "Travel Activity",
            "create_time": "2016-09-23T06:12:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is two issues

1. i'm not getting **count key** in postTag array
2. Can anyone tell a method to get tag_name in **postTag** array instead of containing whole array **tag array** see response

I gets tired of paying efforts in instanceMethod see in model. save me please

Comment: Hey, can you carefully update your code, because it's obvious that some parts, which are commented out are actually not.

Comment: commented code responsible only for for tag detail. as see in repose  "tag": {
            "tag_id": 8,
            "tag_name": "Hiking",
            "tag_type": "Travel Activity",
            "create_time": "2016-09-23T06:12:00.000Z"
          }